# MATLAB forbid `end` as class method input

Tags: matlab

```matlab
classdef Dog
    methods
        function out = bark(obj, text)
%             disp(text)
            out = 1;
        end

        function ind = end(~, ~, ~)
            error("`end` forbidden")
        end
    end
end
```

`d=Dog()`, `d(end)` will error but `d.bark(end)` won't.

- Uncommenting `disp(text)` instead errors as `Not enough input arguments`, but that's not same as forbidding `end` as input to `bark`.
- `d.bark(end, end)` errors as `Too many input arguments`.

Can `end` be forbidden (or detected) as input to any method of `d`?

Comment: Using `end` as a function input like that has odd behaviour, it also destroys the input list, i.e. `d.bark(123, end, 'abc')` comes through as a function call with no inputs. Would it help us to know what behaviour you are trying to protect against?  When `end` is such a commonly-used built in it seems odd to try and mess with it

Comment: @Wolfie Hmm I guess as long as that's commonly understood then it's no problem. I'm implementing a Pythonic list, and if `end` can index then one may expect `list.pop(end)` to also be valid, so I may just ban `end` and replace it with negative indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `d.bark(end)` calls `d.bark` first, obtaining the output array `out`, then calls `end(out,1,1)`. This `end` is not your overloaded function, it is the version for whatever type `out` is, which in your case is `double`. So this is the built-in `out`. This `end` returns 1. Finally, it calls `d.bark(1)`.

I think this is a strange behavior. MATLAB only does this for class methods, not for free functions. For example `sqrt(end)` or `eps(end)` give the error "The end operator must be used within an array index expression.".

I don't think there is a way around this, it is built-in MATLAB behavior, it would require changing the interpreter to override the behavior.

Comment: An idea's to force communication between `bark` and `end` via timers and internal attributes, but who got time for that.